# Towards a standard day count convention in Finance, what the standard should be?

Tags: finance, daycounting

I recently found out about the multitude of day count conventions in Finance (e.g.[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention) and [stackexchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/which-day-count-conventions-are-there-and-where-do-they-apply)). As far as I understand the reason for this variety is a long history of diverse usage.

Would I be correct to expect that in the (perhaps near) future a global standard will emerge? If so is there any of the current conventions a good candidate for a global standard?

Comment: unfortunately most of the answer is encapsulated by https://xkcd.com/927/ . Many of the day count conventions are there for practical as well as historical reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

It is a detail that is important to get right, but otherwise uninteresting. There is no point in changing a convention once you've set one. There are some more common ones associated with the biggest markets, like Act/360, but that's all.

Day count conventions are well documented. There is a degree of consolidation via ISDA standard contracts in the IRS market, but it is limited.